# In python, is a function return a shallow or deep copy?

Tags: python, reference, deep-copy, shallow-copy

In python, if I have

```
x = y
```

any modification to x will also modify y, and I can do

```
x = deepcopy(y)
```

if I want to avoid modifying y while working on x

Say, instead, that I have:

```
myFunc():
    return y

def main():
    x = myFunc()
```

Is it still the case that modifying x will modify y, or since it is a return from another function it will be like a deepcopy?

Comment: Can you be more specific.  In your case it's not clear where does 'y' come from.  The code you posted will not run because 'y' is not known

Comment: Functions don't return any sort of copies. In other words, it is neither.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will be a shallow copy, as nothing has been explicitly copied.

```
def foo(list):
    list[1] = 5
    return list
```

For example:

```
>>> listOne = [1, 2]
>>> listTwo = [3, 4]
>>> listTwo = listOne
>>> foo(listTwo)
[1, 5]
>>> listOne
[1, 5]
```

Answer (score 21):

In python everything is a reference. Nothing gets copied unless you explicitly copy it.

In your example, `x` and `y` reference the same object.

Comment: I think this is a really important principle to learn in Python: assignment *never* makes a copy. You can extend that to function returns as well.

Comment: I knew that about assignment in a function, I was not sure about return because I think it is different in Java

Comment: Why does extending a list  of ravel()ed ndarrays does not create a shallow copy of the original ndarrays?