# Does a property's getter method return a shallow copy

Tags: python

I know that functions in python always return references of variables. I was curious if the getter methods of properties return deep copies, or if the getter methods are only formalities and return references as well.

Comment: "I know that functions in python always return shallow copies of variables" No, they do not. Variables aren't copied anyway, *objects* are copied. Python never implicitly copies objects. The only times copies are created are when you tell them to be created. `property.__get__` works like any other function in that regard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160

Comment: @RobertHarvey sure, but I think OP has an even more fundamental misunderstanding here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I'm not sure you're explaining it correctly.  If Python works like most other programming languages, a copy of *something* is always made during parameter passing: either a *reference* or a *value*

Comment: @RobertHarvey a `PyObject` pointer is passed by value underneath the hood in CPython. That is neither here nor there though. Anyway, there are many different [evaluation strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy). In principle, Python could be implemented without using call by value in C underneath the hood.

Answer (score 5):

All methods return references to objects unless you explicitly tell them to make copies (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032384/in-python-is-a-function-return-a-shallow-or-deep-copy)). A getter method works the same as any other method, meaning that it will return a reference rather than a copy. However, if you want to return a copy, you can use the copy module:

```
import copy

myvar = "abc"
myvar2 = copy.copy(myvar)
```

In this code, changing `myvar` will not change `myvar2` and vice versa. However, if you do this:

```
myvar = "abc"
myvar2 = myvar
```

modifying `myvar` will also modify `myvar2` and vice versa, because `myvar` and `myvar2` refer to the same object.

Python uses something called [call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) when passing arguments to functions. This basically means that a reference to an object is passed to functions. This allows modifying of the arguments passed to a function.

Comment: A copy is still a reference.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga technically, yes, but it is not a reference to the variable it was copied from.

Comment: References aren't to *variables*, they are to *objects*. I think you need to be precise, because OP is quite confused.

Comment: The elephant in the room: the OP needs a better understanding of *pass by value* and *pass by reference* (and passing references by value).

Comment: @RobertHarvey the term you are looking for is [*call by sharing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing), sometimes termed "call by assignment". The whole "passing references by value" is a Javaism. Python is a pure OOP language, everything is an object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Hmm, the things I'm reading on the Internet suggest that, while things happen differently under the hood, the net outcome is the same: Python appears to essentially have "call by value" and "call by reference" semantics, internal implementation details notwithstanding.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it.  Primitives in Python are always *boxed.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey well really, **there are no primitive types in Python**. Everything is full-fledged object. That's why you can do `(42).to_bytes(8, 'big')`. Anyway, Python definitely does not even appear to have call by reference. I can understand thinking it has call by value