# Is safe to return a list to itself from shallow copy in python?

Tags: python, copy, mutable

For the following python code

```
def swap_elements(a):
    a[1], a[0] = a[0], a[1]
    return a

a = [2, 3]
a = swap_elements(a)
print(a)
```

, the function `swap_elements` will modify `a` to itself by `a = swap_elements(a)`. From what I understood, it is a shallow copy (ref the accepted answer in [In python, is a function return a shallow or deep copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032384/in-python-is-a-function-return-a-shallow-or-deep-copy)   and `a=` here) , which uses the same addresses in the memory. Since the function `swap_elements` shallow copies itself to itself, is there any possible issue in locating memory?

E.g., if the shallow copy is doing

a[1] ----> a[2]  # in this step a[1] changed

a[2] ----> a[1]  # will a[1] at the right-hand side adopts the a[1] in the first step at the left-hand side or the old a[1]?

Is safer to use
`b = swap_elements(a)`

or
`a = copy.deepcopy(swap_elements(a))`?

or
simply `swap_elements(a)`, not adding `a=`?

I did not find any issue from my experience, but I am not sure if this will lead to problems in general circumstances.

Comment: No where in your code do you make a copy of the list

Comment: The accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032384/in-python-is-a-function-return-a-shallow-or-deep-copy said as a shallow copy?

Comment: The answer with the most votes on the question is correct https://stackoverflow.com/a/42032437/548562. You are just passing around a reference to a single list object

Comment: So in the accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032384/in-python-is-a-function-return-a-shallow-or-deep-copy/42032437#42032437, why `listOne` changed its value? is that due to it is modified in `list[1] = 5` and within the scope of variable, but not really about shallow copy issue, is that correct? And in my code `a = swap_elements(a)`, is `=` a shallow copy (perhaps i should not add `a=`)?

Comment: In the answer, the line `listTwo = listOne`  makes `listTwo` reference the same object as `listOne` so when the `foo` function is run it updates the __one__ list that both variables reference. The `=` operator doesn't copy anything, it just makes the name/variable on the left side reference/point-to the object on the right, `a = b` just makes the variable/name `a` now reference the same object that `b` references, no copying involved

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: @quamrana thanks. I am reading the link.